# How to copy live shape property settings from one shape to another in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, creative-cloud, layer-style

Does anyone know if there is a way to copy Live Shape Properties from one shape to another?

It's nice to adjust strokes and fill and stuff, but I'd like to save it somehow to easily apply it to other shapes (equivalent styles for layer-configurations).

[image: Screenshot of Live Shape Properties Panel in Adobe CC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the shape layer you want to copy styles from in the layers panel, and choose `Copy Shape Attributes`.
2. Right click the shape layer you want to paste the styles on in the layers panel, and choose `Paste Shape Attributes`.

[image: Option list shown when user right clicks a shape layer in the layers panel]

Answer (score 0):

Something that is a little frustrating with <kbd>Copy Shape Attributes</kbd> and <kbd>Paste Shape Attributes</kbd> is that you can not assign a keyboard shortcut to it. If any one has figured out a way to do this, please enlighten my ignorance.

But until then I have created an action that assigns <kbd>F1+⌘+⇧</kbd> to <kbd>Copy Shape Attributes</kbd> and <kbd>F2+⌘+⇧</kbd> to <kbd>Paste Shape Attributes</kbd>. I hope this is useful for a few people who would like to quickly copy all of the shape attributes.

If you happen to have Keyboard Maestro I have also included the Macro Library if you want to save your fingers from having to stretch so far.

[Download from Dropbox: Photoshop Actions and Keyboard Maestro Macro Library](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u5cr2f5rffwtp8f/AAA2BdhCjnIIVajbuqmjqJH9a?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks Dom! I'm new to stack exchange. Pardon my ignorance on posting. I'm sure I'll find my feet very quickly. Should I delete my post from here once I've posted a question?